# Rails Newbie, nested fields_for not showing on edit when there is no existing record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like an existing user to be able to create a "constant" record for themselves that will be used later to perform calculations. I am using devize.

When I "edit profile", there are no fields shown for dealer_constant, if none exist in the db.

app/models/user.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name,           :dealer_constant_attributes
    has_one :dealer_constant
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :dealer_constant
```

app/views/user/edit.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :dealer_constant do |builder| %>
    <%= render "dealer_constant_fields", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
```

app/views/user/_dealer_constant_fields.html.erb

```
    <%= f.label :crew_size %>
    <%= f.number_field :crew_size %>
    <%= f.label :hourly_rate %>
    <%= f.text_field :hourly_rate %>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the user does not have a dealer_constant at the time of edit, the fields are not showing up. What you need is following:

In **user.rb** add this method

```
def with_dealer_constant
  self.biuld_dealer_constant if self.dealer_constant.nil?
  self
end
```

Then, in **app/views/user/edit.html.erb** view file, do this:

```
<%= form_for([resource_name, resource.with_dealer_constant], url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :dealer_constant do |builder| %>
    <%= render "dealer_constant_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <!-- rest of the fields -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: Many thanks, slapping myself on the forehead.  Much appreciated, solved a very annoying issue.